# Why is "Chopsticks" named so?

Tags: title, chopsticks

I have seen the movie *[Chopsticks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chopsticks_(film))* on Netflix. It has been released on 31st May 2019. How this title is relevant to this movie? I know the characters eat food by using chopsticks. But, why is this movie named so?

(The pair of chopsticks which Nirma (*[Mithila Palkar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mithila_Palkar)*) struggles with in the beginning. Though the artist (*[Abhay Deol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abhay_Deol)*) lovingly teaches her how to use them, she rejects them at the end, choosing to use her hands instead. 
How does this chopsticks pair relate to the film's story?)

Comment: Did you search through [interviews with director Abhay Deol](https://www.google.com/search?q=chopsticks+netflix+director+interview)?

Comment: @JanDoggen is there answer in some interview? If yes then why not answer it

Comment: @ankit After reading one, I did not want to take the time to go through all others. At least this gives the OP or someone else a lead.

Comment: @JanDoggen, Sachin Yardi is the director of that movie, not Abhay Deol.

Comment: @Shree Ah, missed that, I have not seen the movie either. If you look at my Google search URL you'll see that I actually searched for *director*, not a name. Can't edit my comment any longer, too bad. BTW, did you just edit a (possible) answer into your question? Don't do that, just answer your own question below.

Comment: @JanDoggen, that is not answer.

Comment: @Shree it looks like an answer to me

Comment: @OrangeDog, I have given more explanation to support my question. Whatever I have written there, that is 1 minute part of movie. So, how it relates to movie name?

Comment: I found this interesting analysis by [Akhil Arora](https://gadgets.ndtv.com/entertainment/reviews/chopsticks-review-netflix-india-movie-trailer-cast-release-date-mithila-palkar-2044624), but it's not official: "The Netflix film's title stems from the eponymous cutlery that is associated with East Asia, which represents Nirma's desire to shape herself and blend in with the Chinese clients she entertains, in a relentless pursuit to improve her confidence that involves motivation tapes and being mocked by her peers."

Comment: @AnneDaunted, you can elaborate this in answer

Comment: I haven't seen the movie, but since movies are predictable, I can guess, that since she tried to learn to use chopsticks and later given it up, the overall story of the movie is about her trying to be someone else/fitting in but at the end decided to be just herself? Then chopsticks in the title would point to the analogy of her life being like chopsticks. Trial and error and later embracing your hands.

Comment: @TymekWojnarowski, you may be right. Please explore it in answer

Comment: If I would have seen the movie, then I would make a proper answer, but this is only my guess.

Answer (score 2):

According to the director, Sachin Yardi, the film is named “Chopsticks” because:

> ...it is kind of a symbolic way of showing how this girl who does not have a grip on life who eventually does...you realize why it’s “chopsticks” because it starts off with her using...

From an [interview on YouTube](https://youtu.be/iHe-iPRDcrk) starting at 00:16.